# How can I solve the error for connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am getting an error for connecting to the sql error is named pipes provider could not open a connection to SQL Server 1265. Here is the code and it worked yesterday and when I check it today it is not working and I get the error.

Here is the vb code:

```
'Require all variables to be defined
'to prevent rogue variables and limit
'debugging time
Option Explicit


'====================================================================================
' GLOBAL VARIABLES
'====================================================================================
Private Const g_sqlServer = "EWNVM-2017U3"
Private g_lStartDate As Long
Private g_nDaysInMonth As Integer


Public Enum mrReportType
    mrDailyReport
    mrMonthlyReport
    mrYearlyReport
End Enum



'====================================================================================
' GetData(nYear, nMonth)
'====================================================================================
Public Sub GetData(ByVal eReportType As mrReportType, ByVal nYear As Integer, Optional ByVal nMonth As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal nDay As Integer)
  '  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim cMRReport As New MRReport
    Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSqlQuery As String
    Dim sStartDateFmt As String
    Dim i, k As Integer
    Dim sLink As String
    
    'Get Start Date
    g_lStartDate = cMRReport.GetStartDate(nYear, nMonth, nDay)
    
   
    
    'Write report Date to RawData sheet to use on other sheets
    RawData.Range("A1") = Format(g_lStartDate, "mm/yyyy")
    
    'Show Progress Bar Form
    cMRReport.ShowProgressBar
    
    
    '===========================================================================================================================================
    'Historian Database Queries
    '===========================================================================================================================================
    adoConn.ConnectionString = "Provider='SQLNCLI11';Data Source='" & g_sqlServer & "';Initial Catalog='MR_Carrolton_DB';User ID='mrsystems';Password='Reggie#123';"
    adoConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
    adoConn.Open
    
    'Daily Report Type
    
            RawData.Range("B4", "AZ39").ClearContents
            cMRReport.SetHeader Sheet2, Positioncenter, "Monthly WAS Tank Blower Runtimes Report" & vbCr & Format(g_lStartDate, "mmmm yyyy")
            cMRReport.SetHeader Sheet2, PositionRight, "Pee Dee River WWTP" & vbCr & "City of Florence, SC"
            QueryRuntimesDaily adoConn, adoRS, cMRReport
  
    
    'Close Historian DB Connection
    adoConn.Close
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    'Cleanup memory by closing
    'classes we initialized
    Set adoRS = Nothing
    Set adoConn = Nothing
    Set cMRReport = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'Clean Up
    If Not adoConn Is Nothing Then
        If adoConn.State = adStateOpen Then adoConn.Close
    End If
    Set adoConn = Nothing
    
    cMRReport.HandleError err, "Report", "GetData"
End Sub


'===========================================================================================================================================
'Historian Database Queries Functions
'===========================================================================================================================================


'-----------------------------------------
'Query for Flow Totals Daily
'-----------------------------------------
Private Sub QueryRuntimesDaily(ByVal adoConn As ADODB.Connection, ByRef adoRS As ADODB.Recordset, cMRReport As MRReport)
  '  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim sSqlQuery As String
    Dim i As Integer
     Dim startDateSerial
    Dim endDateSerial
    startDateSerial = CDec(DateAdd("n", 1 * i, g_lStartDate))
  '  MsgBox startDateSerial
        endDateSerial = CDec(DateAdd("n", 1 * i + 15, g_lStartDate))
  '      MsgBox endDateSerial
    For i = 0 To 95
      '  sSqlQuery = "SELECT LogDateTime, CL2_RESIDUAL,ZW1_TURBIDITY,ZW2_TURBIDITY,ZW3_TURBIDITY,ZW4_TURBIDITY FROM MR_Carrolton_DB.dbo.DailyRuntimes ORDER BY LogDateTime"
         sSqlQuery = "SELECT LogDateTime, CL2_RESIDUAL " & _
                   " FROM MR_Carrolton_DB.dbo.DailyRuntimes" & _
                   " WHERE LogDateTime >= " & startDateSerial & _
                   " AND LogDateTime < " & endDateSerial & _
                   " ORDER BY LogDateTime"
        'Copy sSqlQuery value to RawData worksheet for troubleshooting
        RawData.Range("B2").Value = sSqlQuery
        
        'Open recordset (executes SQL query)
        adoRS.Open sSqlQuery, adoConn, 0, 1, 1
  
        'If recordset is not empty then copy data to raw sheet
        If adoRS.BOF = False And adoRS.EOF = False Then
            RawData.Cells((i + 4), 2).CopyFromRecordset adoRS
        End If
        
        'Close recordset after each query
        adoRS.Close
        
        'Update Progress Bar
        cMRReport.UpdateProgressBar i, 96, "Querying for Daily Runtimes..."
        
        'Prevent VBA from locking up Excel
        'while running through loops
        DoEvents
    Next i
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'Clean Up
    If Not adoConn Is Nothing Then
        If adoConn.State = adStateOpen Then adoConn.Close
    End If
    Set adoConn = Nothing
    
    cMRReport.HandleError err, "Report", "QueryRuntimesMonthly"
End Sub



'-----------------------------------------
' Lock/Unlock Worksheets
'-----------------------------------------
Public Sub LockWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect "reggie"
    Next
End Sub


Public Sub UnLockWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect "reggie"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (this should contain full error message).

Comment: Please provide the error you received

Comment: I also suggest you remove the login and password from your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is more of server administration issue than a coding one. Ping your server to check if there is connectivity problem. Your connection does not persist so you must check your "hosts" file and Sql Server settings if they are properly set.

Visit this page for step by step troubleshooting:
[Resolving could not open a connection to sql server errors](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/)